# Embed Power BI Reports in Oracle JET

Tags: powerbi

I have initiated a 60 day trial version of Power BI . I have 2 questions here

1) Is that Trial Version enough to do a small POC on integrating Power BI with Oracle JET

2)Basically I have a Javascript Client Framework Oracle JET where i need to embed the Power BI report Any Document where i can initiate the development as i am very new to this

Thanks

Vikram

Answer (score 1):

60 days trial is enough for any POC but it again it depends on the individual. You can refer to [Oracle JET Cookbook](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html) which itself makes it easy for developers to start.